# vnext builds failed with robocopy command in projects

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild, tfs-2015, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

i'm using TFS2015 and vnext builds to build projects and sln files with build controller
in projects or slns we use robocopy command to copy dlls from builded solution to other folders but sometimes this job done and vnext build passed successfully and sometimes robocopy command can't copy dlls and failed with error

is there anyone solved this problem, can help me ?

1-my build agents run with Network/Service User

2-robocopy command error exited with code 8.

Comment: Try to queue build with `system.debug = true`, and you'll get more information in the log. Check the log to get detailed error message.

Answer (score 0):

Error 8 from Robocopy means that some files or directories could not be copied at that moment. Since you are saying that the command sometimes succeeds, more likely is either a specific time related issue, or probably the files are being used by some other process at the time when the command is executed. In both cases you could try to execute the same robocopy command manually several minutes later, and see if it will fail again. You could add a /v option in your robocopy command (and possibly /LOG), and verify if there is more descriptive error in the log file afterwards. Also, when it fails, is the environment same as the one, on which it succeeds?

Comment: thanks a lot
but i have tfs2013 with xaml builds,and when i build slns with xaml builds don't have problem and build passed success!and robocopy work correctly,when build slns with vnext builds and tfs2015 i got error !
What is your opinion about this issue?

Comment: Since both build systems are quite different, it is possible that the timing of the execution of that robocopy command to be different than when are executed in a XAML build. In the new build system, you have the ability to look at the failing steps' log, and why exactly it is failing, on top of verifying the log from the robocopy command.